# Convert SQL Server result set into string

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I am getting the result in SQL Server as

```
SELECT StudentId FROM Student WHERE condition = xyz
```

I am getting the output like

```
StudentId
1236

7656

8990
........
```

The output parameter of the stored procedure is `@studentId` string and I want the return statement as

```
1236, 7656, 8990.
```

How can I convert the output in the single string?

I am returning single column [ie. StudentId]

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Test this:

```
 DECLARE @result NVARCHAR(MAX)

 SELECT @result = STUFF(
                        (   SELECT ',' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(20), StudentId) 
                            FROM Student 
                            WHERE condition = abc 
                            FOR xml path('')
                        )
                        , 1
                        , 1
                        , '')
```

Comment: works a treat. I got to replace dozens of while loops that I inherited for getting emails into a single string.

Answer (score 66):

```
DECLARE @result varchar(1000)

SELECT @result = ISNULL(@result, '') + StudentId + ',' FROM Student WHERE condition = xyz

select substring(@result, 0, len(@result) - 1) --trim extra "," at end
```

Comment: I've just tried this code and it works. Just minor adjustment:
select substring(@result, 1, len(@result) -1 ) to remove the extra ","

Comment: Tried this and the last line doesn't work correctly in SQL Server 2008. `substring(@result, 1, len(@result) )` removes the trailing comma, whereas the version above removes the character before the comma as well. :)

Comment: should be `substring(@result, 1, len(@result) - 1)`  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms187748.aspx

Comment: If the StudentId is coming from a non varchar column, you will probably get a conversion exception. You need to use the CONCAT function to do proper concatenation. See answer below.

Answer (score 12):

Use the `COALESCE` function:

```
DECLARE @StudentID VARCHAR(1000)
SELECT @StudentID = COALESCE(@StudentID + ',', '') + StudentID
FROM Student
WHERE StudentID IS NOT NULL and Condition='XYZ'
select @StudentID
```

Comment: If the StudentId is coming from a non varchar column, you will probably get a conversion exception. You need to use the CONCAT function to do proper concatenation. See answer below.

Answer (score 8):

Both answers are valid, but don't forget to initializate the value of the variable, by default is NULL and with T-SQL:

```
NULL + "Any text" => NULL
```

It's a very common mistake, don't forget it!

Also is good idea to use ISNULL function:

```
SELECT @result = @result + ISNULL(StudentId + ',', '') FROM Student
```

Comment: Reference to "Both answers" is kind of useless as answers move around and there are more than 2.

Answer (score 6):

Use the `CONCAT` function to avoid conversion errors:

```
DECLARE @StudentID VARCHAR(1000)
SELECT @StudentID = CONCAT(COALESCE(@StudentID + ',', ''), StudentID)
FROM Student
WHERE StudentID IS NOT NULL and Condition='XYZ'
select @StudentID
```

Answer (score 3):

The following is a solution for MySQL (not SQL Server), i couldn't easily find a solution to this on stackoverflow for mysql, so i figured maybe this could help someone...

ref: https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?10,285268,285286#msg-285286

original query...

`SELECT StudentId FROM Student WHERE condition = xyz`

original result set...

```
StudentId
1236
7656
8990
```

new query w/ concat...

```
SELECT group_concat(concat_ws(',', StudentId) separator '; ') 
FROM Student 
WHERE condition = xyz
```

concat string result set...

```
StudentId
1236; 7656; 8990
```

note: change the 'separator' to whatever you would like

GLHF!

Answer (score 2):

Use STRING_AGG:

```
SELECT STRING_AGG(sub.StudentId, ',') FROM  
(select * from dbo.Students where Name = 'Test3') as sub
```

If you want to use e.g ORDER BY:

```
SELECT STRING_AGG(sub.StudentId, ',') WITHIN GROUP(Order by StudentId) FROM  
(select * from dbo.Students where Name = 'Test3') as sub
```

Answer (score 1):

This one works with NULL Values in Table and doesn't require substring operation at the end. COALESCE is not really well working with NULL values in table (if they will be there).

```
DECLARE @results VARCHAR(1000) = '' 
SELECT @results = @results + 
           ISNULL(CASE WHEN LEN(@results) = 0 THEN '' ELSE ',' END + [StudentId], '')
FROM Student WHERE condition = xyz

select @results
```

Answer (score 1):

The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4819751/9969381) from [brad.v](https://stackoverflow.com/users/28616/brad-v) is incorrect! It won't give you a concatenated string.

Here's the correct code, almost like [brad.v](https://stackoverflow.com/users/28616/brad-v)'s but with one important change:

```
DECLARE @results VarChar(1000)
  SELECT @results = CASE
     WHEN @results IS NULL THEN CONVERT( VarChar(20), [StudentId])
     ELSE @results + ', ' + CONVERT( VarChar(20), [StudentId])
  END
FROM Student WHERE condition = abc;
```

See the difference? :) [brad.v](https://stackoverflow.com/users/28616/brad-v) please fix your answer, I can't do anything to correct it or comment on it 'cause my reputation here is zero. I guess I can remove mine after you fix yours. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

or a single select statement...

```
DECLARE @results VarChar(1000)
SELECT @results = CASE
     WHEN @results IS NULL THEN CONVERT( VarChar(20), [StudentId])
     ELSE ', ' + CONVERT( VarChar(20), [StudentId])
   END
FROM Student WHERE condition = abc;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assign a value when declaring the variable.

```
DECLARE @result VARCHAR(1000) ='';

SELECT @result = CAST(StudentId AS VARCHAR) + ',' FROM Student WHERE condition = xyz
```