# Transform a SELECT * query to string

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query that returns a row

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE id = 1;
```

I want to save the result into a nvarchar sql variable. I have seen similar questions [Convert SQL Server result set into string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4819412/convert-sql-server-result-set-into-string) but they only use select with the name of the columns, never with *.

```
select *
from table
where id = 1
for xml path ('')
```

However the answer is `<column1>value1</column1> <column2>value2</column2>` and I just want it to be `value1, value2`

Is there a way to achieve this? thank you!

Comment: Easiest solution `SELECT CONCAT(column1,',',column2) FROM table` - why do you need `*`?

Comment: Please can you show us the data you get with the first query ?

Answer (score 1):

If open to a helper function.

This will convert virtually any row, table or query to a string (delimited or not).

In the following examples I selected a PIPE delimiter with a CRLF line terminator.

Please note the usage and placement of `_RN` when a line terminator is required.  Also note the `,ELEMENTS XSINIL` ... this will included null values as empty string.  If you want to exclude null values, simply omit the `,ELEMENTS XSINIL`

**Example as Entire Table or [dbFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=a3ab001e5147c6e227e6558290d4588b)**

```
Declare @YourTable Table (id int,[col_1] varchar(50),[col_2] varchar(50),[col_3] varchar(50),[col_n] varchar(50))  Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 (1,'data1','data2','data3','data4')
,(2,'data5','data6','data7','data8')

-- Entire Table 
Declare @XML xml = (Select *,_RN=Row_Number() over (Order By (Select null)) From @YourTable for XML RAW,ELEMENTS XSINIL )
Select [dbo].[svf-str-Data-To-Delimited]('|',char(13)+char(10),@XML)
```

**Returns**

```
1|data1|data2|data3|data4
2|data5|data6|data7|data8
```

**Example as Row Based**

```
Select A.ID
      ,AsAString = [dbo].[svf-str-Data-To-Delimited]('|',char(13)+char(10),B.XMLData)
 From  @YourTable A
Cross Apply ( values ( (select a.* for xml RAW,ELEMENTS XSINIL )) )B(XMLData)
```

**Returns**

```
ID  AsAString
1   1|data1|data2|data3|data4
2   2|data5|data6|data7|data8
```

**The Function if Interested**

```
CREATE Function [dbo].[svf-str-Data-To-Delimited] (@Delim varchar(50),@EOL varchar(50),@XML xml)
Returns varchar(max)
Begin

Return(
        Select convert(nvarchar(max),(
            Select case when Item='_RN' then ''
                        else case when nullif(lead(Item,1) over (Order by Seq),'_RN') is not null  
                                  then concat(Value,@Delim)
                                  else concat(Value,@EOL)
                        end 
                    end
             From (
                    Select Seq   = row_number() over(order by (select null))
                          ,Item  = xAttr.value('local-name(.)', 'nvarchar(100)')
                          ,Value = xAttr.value('.','nvarchar(max)')
                     From  @XML.nodes('/row/*') xNode(xAttr)
                   ) A
             Order By Seq
             For XML Path (''),TYPE).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)') )
)

End
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily store the result as an XML string:

```
select *
from (values (1, 'x', getdate())) v(id, a, b)
where id = 1
for xml path ('');
```

Or as a JSON string:

```
select *
from (values (1, 'x', getdate())) v(id, a, b)
where id = 1
for json auto;
```

Comment: Thank you, however, if I use that code I get   < column1>value1< /column> value2 and I just want it to be value1, value2

Comment: Your might find that `FOR XML AUTO` or `FOR XML RAW` is closer to what you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind Using dynamic SQL (and INFORMATION_SCHEMA dictionary), for example, for SQL Server this works:

`DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = '',
        @result nvarchar(max),
        @id int = 1
SELECT @sql += '+'',''+convert(nvarchar,' + QUOTENAME(column_name) +')' from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns where table_name = 'Student' 
SET @sql = 'select @result=' + stuff(@sql,1,5,'') + ' from student where id = ' + CAST(@id as nvarchar)
EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql, N'@result nvarchar(max) OUTPUT', @result=@result OUTPUT
SELECT @result as MyOutput`